# 2.79 Hair dynamics bake didn't write in cache

Tags: particles, physics

I have a big problem with particles cache, when i try to bake my hair simulation, it calculate normaly, but after ended (and it's long) i see 0 frames on disk and my disk cache weighs 1 ko.

[image]

I try to delete this, remake with diferent folder, files, nothing do it.
Actually i use 2.79 for this scene because 2.80 have many prob for baking.

But I didn't think to block like this on this stage.

Need help please, I had to forget one thing!

Comment: Oh it's ok I have found ! Just uncheck "Regrow" when you want animate hair ! xD

Answer (score 0):

It's ok for me.

For other people, think to not check "Regrow" when you want animate hair, and you didn't loss a time like me ^^

Care this !

[image]